# What are a recent, compatible set of Jars for using Cucumber with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, cucumber

I am looking for the list of jar files, and their versions, that are able to run cucumber within Eclipse.

In order to run Cucumber in Eclipse I need a compatible set of Jar files. I am using a very out of date set because I am finding it impossible to work out a new set that work together. Below is the list if Jars I am using and which I know work .. which are several years out of date:

cucumber-core-1.2.6.jar
cucumber-html-0.2.6.jar
cucumber-java-1.2.6.jar
cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
cucumber-reporting-3.12.0.jar
gherkin-2.12.2.jar
junit-4.12.jar
mockito-all-2.0.2-beta.jar

This morning I downloaded a similar set of 'most recent' version .. and they give errors:

cucumber-core-6.7.0.jar
cucumber-html-0.2.7.jar
cucumber-java-6.7.0.jar
cucumber-junit-6.7.0.jar
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
cucumber-report-generator-1.3.5.jar
cucumber-reporting-5.3.1.jar
gherkin-15.0.2.jar
hamcrest-2.2.jar
junit-4.13.jar

Is there anywhere a configuration list of known working versions?

Comment: https://search.maven.org has a search engine for Maven Central (and you should be using Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

> This morning I downloaded a similar set of 'most recent' version .. and they give errors:

If you follow the [10 minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) you'll get an introduction that uses Maven dependency management. And I would strongly urge you to invest time in learning either Maven or Gradle. Amongst other things these tools will automate your dependency management and this can make your life much easier.

For example:

If you want to use Cucumber with JUnit 4 and annotation based step definitions you would declare this minimal set of dependencies in a Maven `pom.xml` file.

```
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>6.7.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

By telling Maven what your dependencies are Maven can calculate your transitive dependencies i.e: the dependencies of your dependencies.

This has many advantages. One example would be using the `mvn dependency:tree` command to list all dependencies. This is much faster and much less error prone then downloading jar files by hand and hoping that you have the right ones.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-messages:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:messages:jar:13.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:10.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:9.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:create-meta:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:jar:6.7.0:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.879 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-19T18:32:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So I do understand that this is the 'right' way to do this. And I am tempted. My issue is that, whenever I follow a solution like this I end up trapped down a rabbit hole of then trying to make a second tool work .. which invariably won't. I am nervous about getting stuck trying to instal / learn Maven when my goal is really to learn Cucumber.

Comment: Understanding build tools is a foundational skill that enables and accelerates many other skills. You have to automate your own development process as much as you automate your tests. I would recommend learning how to develop and test an application with gradle/maven/java/junit before going into Cucumber.