# Running Cucumber 6.7 in Eclipse throws error: Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to run sample cucumber feature file in eclipse but seeing below error. I have added the cucumber-core, cucumber-java, cucumber-jvm-deps and gherkins jars to the build path.

> WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use
> io.cucumber.core.cli.Main Exception in thread "main"
> java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
> java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)  at
> java.util.Collections.max(Unknown Source)     at
> io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:43)
> at java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(Unknown Source)   at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$processResource$1(ResourceScanner.java:79)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:70)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:55)
> at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)     at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:48)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:28)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:61)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:134)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
> at
> io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:45)
> at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:78)    at
> io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:79)   at
> cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)   at
> cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970528/what-are-a-recent-compatible-set-of-jars-for-using-cucumber-with-eclipse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are a recent, compatible set of Jars for using Cucumber with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970528/what-are-a-recent-compatible-set-of-jars-for-using-cucumber-with-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

in Eclipse > Run Configuration select Main Class as "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
After that you will not see the problem.